# drf_yasg only renders filterset parameters on list view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filters, drf-yasg

I have defined a filterset for a DRF ViewSet.  drf_yasg correctly renders all the filterset fields as parameters in Swagger for the *list* endpoint, but not for any other endpoints.

Any idea why?

**views.py:**

```
from rest_framework import mixins, viewsets

from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema

from my_app.models import MyModel
from my_app.serializers import MySerializer

class MyFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = {
            "status",
        }
class MyViewSet(
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
):

    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filterset_class = MyFilterSet
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
```

Answer (score 2):

List is only place where filters are actually used ([see here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py))

```py
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        ...
```

There is nothing to filter on create/update/delete since there are no multiple results. Same goes for retrieve, you are fetching an object by id, so filtering single result doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @nedadp - Thanks.  That does make sense.  But what about: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/cdc956a96caafddcf4ecaf6218e340ebb3ce6d72/rest_framework/generics.py#L83  I can see that GenericViewSet.get_object _does_ call `filter_queryset` ?

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Just tried it, and filtering does work on retrieve/update, but I guess it is either excluded from openapi spec on purpose since it's not supposed to be used like that, or it just ignores GenericViewSet methods and relies on mixins.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that other methods beyond `list` employ `filter_queryset`, `drf-yasg` will only auto populate the filter parameters in the event that it's a `GET` method that returns a list of objects. You can see this decision in the [`inspectors.ViewInspector`](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/blob/master/src/drf_yasg/inspectors/base.py#L331) file.

If you want to see them I can think of two options

1. Extend the `SwaggerAutoSchema` class and allow other HTTP verbs
2. Add a decorator to the `ViewSet` to include some manual parameters. For example, to add it to the `retrieve` method.

```py
@method_decorator(
    name="retrieve", 
    decorator=swagger_auto_schema(
        manual_parameters=[openapi.Parameter("field", openapi.IN_QUERY, description="filter on field", type=openapi.TYPE_STRING)],
    )
)
class MyViewSet(
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
):
...
```